# IBM Watson tone analyzer post request issue

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I am student and learning to code and help from community is appreciated. I have hosted my code in heroku with domain name https://depionicapp.herokuapp.com/. When I am doing post request with postman I am getting Error `500` but with cloud 9 I am able to get the result.

```
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
// Authorizing on a per-API-basis. You don't need to do this if you auth on a 
// global basis (see Authorization section above). 
var express = require('express');
var router = express();

var visionClient = vision({
  projectId: 'ionic-face-api',
  keyFilename: './ionic.json'
});

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var server = http.createServer(router);
router.post('/info', function(req, res) {
  var text = req.body.text;
  console.log(text)
  var ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');

  var tone_analyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    version_date: '2016-05-19'
  });

  tone_analyzer.tone({
      text: text
  }, function(err, tone) {
    if (err)
     console.log(err);
    else
     res.send((JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2)));
  });
});
```

**Postman:**

```
Postman request: https: //depionicapp.herokuapp.com/info
Content - Type: application / json 
Body I am sending from postman
{"text": "I am good.....blah blah..." }// Error 500
```

Answer (score 1):

So, trying to help you. I edit your code deleting the vision module and just create one server in Node.js for test your code, works perfectly.

**File** toneExample.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var router = express();

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/info', function(req, res) {
    var text = req.body.text;
    console.log(text)
    var ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');

    var tone_analyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
     username: 'yourUsername',
     password: 'yourPassword',
     version_date: '2016-05-19'
     });

    tone_analyzer.tone({
        text: text
    }, function(err, tone) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else res.send((JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2)));
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**File** server.js:

```
var server = require('./toneExample.js');
var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server running on port: %d', port);
});
```

After executing `node server.js`, I did one example in POSTMAN for the `/info` endpoint and I get the results successful:

[image]

**Info**:

- Node version: 6.11.2
- Modules installed: `express`, `body-parser`, `watson-developer-cloud`

**Obs.:** If you use the `version_date: 2017-09-21` the return results for the post tone IDs: anger, fear, joy, sadness, analytical, confident, and tentative. And the returns results only for tones whose scores meet a *minimum threshold* of `0.5`.

See more about in the [Official API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/?curl#post-tone). I recommend to you try to check the headers that you need to sent, the type of you can use in your body `post`, some stuffs like that.

Comment: Thanks for response the sir. I will just check.

Comment: Thanks for the great help.I deeply appreciate for the help.Its working now.

Comment: Great! Please **mark** the question following the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from StackOverflow and help others with the same problem.